# Python ArgParse call a group of arguments with one argument

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to populate a group of arguments with only one command?

For example: if I had three arguments (-a --AGE (int), -n --NAME (str), -g --GRADE (int))

Typically I would specify all of these arguments (python main.py -a __ -n __ -g __). Is there a way to make an argument so I could just run python main.py --FOO which would cause (for example) python main.py -a 6 -n Jim -g 2 to run?

Comment: you can specify a text file in arguments from  which you can unpack values

Comment: Conceptually the simplest would be to make `--FOO` as `store_true` argument, and after parsing do a `if args.FOO: args.a, args.n, args.g = 6,'Jim',2`.  Doing it in a custom Action is also possible, but won't be any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom action (which probably involves knowing more about how `-a`, `-n`, and `-g` work than you might want):

```
class ANG(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        setattr(namespace, 'AGE', 6)
        setattr(namespace, 'NAME', 'Jim')
        setattr(namespace, 'GRADE', 2)

...

p.add_argument('--FOO', action=ANG)
```

As far as I know, there's no (simple) way to make `--FOO` just append `-a`, `6`, `-n`, `Jim`, `-g`, and `2` to the list of arguments that `p.parse_args` will parse.

There's also the issue of whether you want subsequent uses of `-a`, `-n`, and/or `-g` to override `--FOO`.